# Neo4j Summing node values in path

Tags: graph, neo4j, neo4jclient

i have this method to to find all paths from a starting node, and return the paths with the sum of the Score value in each node, for each path.

```
public List<PathScore> GetHighScorePath(string nodeName)
    {
        try
        {
            List<PathScore> result =
                this.client.Cypher.Match("p=(n)-[*]->(leaf)")
                .Where((LogEvent n) => n.Name == nodeName)
                .AndWhere("Not ((leaf)-->(n))")
                .ReturnDistinct(p => new PathScore
                {
                    Nodes = Return.As<IEnumerable<Node<LogEvent>>>("nodes(p)"),
                    Relationships = Return.As<IEnumerable<RelationshipInstance<Pivot>>>("rels(p)"),
                    pScore = Return.As<int>("REDUCE(total = 0, n IN nodes(p) | total + n.Score)")
                })
                .Results.ToList();
            return result;

        }}
```

this is my path result class

```
public class PathScore
{
    public IEnumerable<Node<LogEvent>> Nodes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RelationshipInstance<Pivot>> Relationships { get; set; }
    public int pScore;
}
```

But i get this error msg from neo4j

> Neo4j returned a valid response, however Neo4jClient was unable to deserialize into the object structure you supplied.

i believe the error lies with the part where i return the score as part of the returned object. This is the line that is causing the error:

```
pScore = Return.As<int>("REDUCE(total = 0, n IN nodes(p) | total + n.Score)")
```

Comment: ok stupid me. i left out the get set access method for my pScore property

Comment: So does that mean it *is* working now?

Comment: yes it is. its actually a stupid mistake on my part . will post an answer for this to close this off

Comment: We all make those kinds of mistakes! Glad it's sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so its just a mistake where i left out the get/set accessors.

this is the edited version

```
 public class PathScore
{
    public IEnumerable<Node<LogEvent>> Nodes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RelationshipInstance<Pivot>> Relationships { get; set; }
    public int pScore { get; set; }
}
```